# Using small capitals causes missing characters

Tags: fonts, pdftex, characters

For some reason using small capitals `\textsc{}` causes missing characters. For example, the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\textsc{Hello world}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

Renders as:

[image: E ELLO ORLD]

But once I remove the small caps, it renders normally:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

% \textsc{Hello world}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

[image: Hello World]

I have tried using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but it doesn't make a difference.

The logfile looks like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.1)  19 JUN 2022 13:01
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count187
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test
.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 383 strings out of 478994
 6892 string characters out of 5858185
 289938 words of memory out of 5000000
 17948 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 404029 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,50p,169b,100s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc
10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12
.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 18403 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Not sure how to debug this further, as there are no obvious errors/warning. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Edit: The first code snippet is working on Overleaf, so it's probably just something specific to my machine.

Comment: you have cut off the log file before it shows which fonts are used, can you post the remaning lines? also try testing the pdf with a different pdf viewer

Comment: Ah I thought those lines were just stats. Added back now!

Comment: I see nothing in the log file that could hint to problems.

Comment: Hmm don't want to re-install latex, but I might just have to. :(

Comment: re-installing latex will not help if (as is more likely) it is a problem with whatever pdf viewer are using, you have not said which that is, or whether you tried a different one. Although your latex is 2020 so a bit old, you might want to update it for other reasons

Comment: You're absolutely right - it is the pdf viewer. I just opened the pdf with a different viewer and it looks fine! I was using emacs `latex-preview-pane-mode` to view, but I guess it has some issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with latex, but with my pdf viewer. I was using emacs `latex-preview-pane` mode on MacOS to view the pdf. However, on further investigation I found that ghostscript was installed but not properly linked. I fixed this with:

```
brew install ghostscript
brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

I then restarted emacs. After this, the preview pane was able to display small capitals correctly!

Thanks to David Carlisle for pointing me in the right direction here.